# How to return column value in another sheet if a cell contains "Pick up"

Tags: excel

```
in Sheet 1
```

Column E      Column F      Column G

```
kk          A           Pick up
kk          B           Pick down
kl          C           Pick up
```

if Column G  = Pick up & Column E start with "kk" 
then in `Sheet 4` show Column E from sheet 1 add thw word "ok" for every cell

else if 
 Column G = Pick down & Column E  start with "kk" 
then in `Sheet 4` show Column F from sheet 1 add thw word "ok" for every cel

else if  Column E  = kl 
in `Sheet 4` show Column E from sheet 1

> Desired result

```
Column E in Sheet 4

okkk
okB
kl
```

Any idea would be great, thank you

**Edit**

> Sheet 4

[image]

> Sheet 1

[image]

My amended formular

```
=IF(AND(Sheet1!G1="Pick up",LEFT(Sheet1!E1,2)="HK"),"Ok" & Sheet1!F1,IF(AND(Sheet1!G1="delivery",LEFT(Sheet1!E1,2)="HK"),"HK" & Sheet1!F1,IF(Sheet1!E1="Macau",
```

Comment: Try this formula on sheet 4. Btw. What if there isn't Pick up or Pick down in column G?

`=IF(Sheet1!G1="Pick down","ok"&Sheet1!F1,IF(Sheet1!G1="Pick up","ok"&Sheet1!E1,""))`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use this formula in `Sheet4`

```
=IF(Sheet1!G1="Pick Up","Ok" &Sheet1!E1,"Ok"&Sheet1!F1)
```

> Edit

Then use following formula

```
=IF(AND(Sheet1!G1="Pick Up",LEFT(Sheet1!E1,2)="kk"),"Ok" & Sheet1!E1,IF(AND(Sheet1!G1="Pick Down",LEFT(Sheet1!E1,2)="kk"),"Ok" & Sheet1!F1,IF(Sheet1!E1="Kl",Sheet1!E1,"")))
```

Comment: @ Harun24HR  sorry, my bad a bit confuse with my logic, please check my code amendment, thanks

Comment: @ Harun24HR find a bug, the last 2 condition works perfectly, bu the first condition show blank in excel

Comment: Then problem in your data or applying formula. Can you share a sample file via dropbox or google drive so that I can check. I tested the formula and works fine.

Comment: @ Harun24HR I snapshot some pic in excel, please take a look

Comment: @epiphany Hi, I am not sure either the problem with `chinese` letters. Can you please check with English word? I just check with English words and found the formula fine.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/172424/discussion-between-epiphany-and-harun24hr).